# Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?) when using exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am beginner in android i try to use ExoPlayer to show video but i have a problem when trying to run the elumater it crashes and give me that error in the logcat "Unexpected exception loading stream "

**This is my Logcat error**

```html
10-17 17:31:12.619 8321-8631/com.example.abdelmagied.bakingapp E/LoadTask: Unexpected exception loading stream
  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:464)
     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:427)
     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:351)
     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:193)
     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:123)
     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:623)
     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:295)
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
  Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
```

**This is my manifest file**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abdelmagied.bakingapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".recipeDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".recipeFragment" />
        <activity android:name=".stepDetailActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Activity containing Exoplayer**

```html
package com.example.abdelmagied.bakingapp;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.abdelmagied.bakingapp.recipeContents.steps;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.LoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class stepDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  ExoPlayer.EventListener {
    private SimpleExoPlayer mExoPlayer;
    private SimpleExoPlayerView mPlayerView;
    private static MediaSessionCompat mMediaSession;
    private PlaybackStateCompat.Builder mStateBuilder;
    @BindView(R.id.description)
    public TextView descrip;
    private static final String TAG = stepDetailActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_step_detail);

        steps myrecipes = (steps) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("stepDetails");

        mPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);
        initializeMediaSession();
        initializePlayer(Uri.parse("https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/April/58ffd9cb_4-press-crumbs-in-pie-plate-creampie/4-press-crumbs-in-pie-plate-creampie.mp4"));
        descrip.setText(myrecipes.getDescription());

    }
    private void initializePlayer(Uri mediaUri) {
        if (mExoPlayer == null) {
           // Create an instance of the ExoPlayer.
           TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
            LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
            mExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
            mPlayerView.setPlayer(mExoPlayer);

            // Prepare the MediaSource.
            String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "Bakingapp");
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mediaUri, new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                    this, userAgent), new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
            mExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
            mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            // Set the ExoPlayer.EventListener to this activity.
            mExoPlayer.addListener(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the Media Session to be enabled with media buttons, transport controls, callbacks
     * and media controller.
     */
    private void initializeMediaSession() {

        // Create a MediaSessionCompat.
        mMediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, TAG);

        // Enable callbacks from MediaButtons and TransportControls.
        mMediaSession.setFlags(
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                        MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

        // Do not let MediaButtons restart the player when the app is not visible.
        mMediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(null);

        // Set an initial PlaybackState with ACTION_PLAY, so media buttons can start the player.
        mStateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setActions(
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE);

        mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());


        // MySessionCallback has methods that handle callbacks from a media controller.
        mMediaSession.setCallback(new MySessionCallback());

        // Start the Media Session since the activity is active.
        mMediaSession.setActive(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        if((playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) && playWhenReady){
            mStateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING,
                    mExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), 1f);
        } else if((playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY)){
            mStateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED,
                    mExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), 1f);
        }
        mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

    }

    /**
     * Media Session Callbacks, where all external clients control the player.
     */
    private class MySessionCallback extends MediaSessionCompat.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToPrevious() {
            mExoPlayer.seekTo(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my XML layout**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.abdelmagied.bakingapp.stepDetailActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        >
    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id = "@+id/description"
              android:text = "som mu"
              android:textSize = "20dp"
              />

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `(No address associated with hostname)` check API

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

https://github.com/anthonycr/Grant

i will help you to manage your permission.

Answer (score 0):

In the [official demo](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) there is a [permissions request handler](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/b2333c86c1eac9a1f95992960a8495f1e5b79200/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java#L189) is overridden, it logs errors and this could possibly give more exact information on the permissions.

In the [manifest](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/b2333c86c1eac9a1f95992960a8495f1e5b79200/demos/main/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L21) multiple network permissions are defined:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

I set those permissions in a [minimal example](https://github.com/bitsmith1010/exo-player-minimal) based on the standard Android Project App template and it functions.